# First check returns good results, but the second function checks returns a 404. Both are practically doing similar things

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, express

Really need some help on this as this is really confusing me alot.

I am building an asset management for project.
I have a check vuln page to perform checks based on the name, version of the entry.
It is not a automated system but just for project purpose.

So the first function and second function or API are doing the same thing, just to check for vulnerability against the NIST vulnerability database.

[Picture Browser of first function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i7dIn.png)

The code for the check of the first function:

```
app.post('/checkVulnerability', function(req, res) {
    const name = req.body.name;
    const version = req.body.version;
    const apiUrl = `https://services.nvd.nist.gov/rest/json/cves/1.0?keyword=${name} ${version}`;
  
    request(apiUrl, function(error, response, body) {
      if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        const result = JSON.parse(body);
        if (result.totalResults == 0) {
          res.send(`<p>${name} ${version} is not vulnerable.</p>`);
        } else {
          let cves = '';
          result.result.CVE_Items.forEach(function(item) {
            cves += `<p><a href="https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/${item.cve.CVE_data_meta.ID}" target="_blank">${item.cve.CVE_data_meta.ID}</a></p>`;
          });
          res.send(`<p>${name} ${version} is vulnerable to the following CVEs:</p>${cves}`);
        }
      } else {
        res.send('An error occurred.');
      }
    });
  });
```

Then I added another function to check existing assets that are stored in the database for vulnerabilities.
Please see picture:

[Picture Browser of second function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fLB6.png)

The code as follows:

```
  app.post('/checkAssetVulnerability', async function(req, res) {
    const name = req.body.name;
    const version = req.body.version;
    const apiUrl = `https://services.nvd.nist.gov/rest/json/cve/1.1/cpe:/a:${name}:${version}`;
  
    request(apiUrl, function(error, response, body) {
      console.log('API response:', response.statusCode, body); // log the API response
  
      if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        const result = JSON.parse(body);
        let vulnerabilities = [];
  
        if (result.result && result.result.CVE_Items && result.result.CVE_Items.length > 0) {
          vulnerabilities = result.result.CVE_Items.map(function(item) {
            return item.cve.CVE_data_meta.ID;
          });
        }
  
        Asset.updateOne({ name: name, version: version }, { vulnerabilities: vulnerabilities }, function(err, raw) {
          if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.send('An error occurred while updating asset vulnerability.');
          } else {
            res.send(`Vulnerability check for ${name} ${version} completed. ${vulnerabilities.length} vulnerabilities found.`);
          }
        });
      } else {
        res.send('An error occurred while checking vulnerability.');
      }
    });
  });
```

For this 2nd function, it does not perform any checks and jump directly to the last else statement.

This is the asset stored in the db:

[Stored in DB asset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOUrx.png)

For this issue, I really want to know why is this happening and how can i fix the code. Been trying to fix for hours. Please help. If required more information please let me know in comments. Thank you.

*Edited*
If i use console.log(error) it logs the following error:
API response: 404 Web Services

### NVD Web Services Endpoint

#### 0.3

Available at: TBD

- Initial public draft

Why is it getting 404 when both functions are checking the same name and version, 1 is getting a response and 1 getting not found.

Comment: `console.log(error)`

Comment: If they are doing the same thing, why is one async and the other not?

Comment: Done a console.log(error) as suggested, updated the post with the error.

Comment: @Joe this is the least of the concern as of now. The functionality of the 2 codes are doing the same thing, 1st one is taking inputs from users and checking it against NIST vdb. 2nd one is taking the stored data in mongodb and checking it against NIST vdb.